# modaless dialog export from mfc extension dll not show

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have built the folowing configuration:

1) MFC extension dll with dialog A(class MultipleTextBox)

2) MFC application has dialog B. (dialog A as the child of dialog B)

dialog B declare a instance of dialog A in header file:

```
private:
    MultipleTextBox* m_pTextBox;
```

in the dialog B's OnInitDialog function:

```
m_pTextBox->CreateDlg(MultipleTextBox::IDD, this);
m_pTextBox->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pTextBox->MoveWindow(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

But dialog A not show when application is running.

Answer (score 0):

This is probable due to missing call of

> AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

give call of above function and then dialog will show in you application.